# Blazor scroll event to certain element

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to accomplish the following in a blazor server app (with tailwind for css):
When the user scrolls down once, the page automatically scrolls to a certain element on the page, here is the code for the razor page (i held it simple because i just want to know why the scroll event isnt working):

```
@page "/TestScroll"

@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<div class="h-48 w-48 m-12 border-gray-900 border-2">
    
</div>
<div class="h-48 w-48 m-12 border-gray-900 border-2">
        
</div>
<div class="h-48 w-48 m-12 border-gray-900 border-2">
        
</div>
<div class="h-48 w-48 m-12 border-gray-900 border-2">
        
</div>
<div class="h-48 w-48 m-12 border-gray-900 border-2">
        
</div>
<div id="testDiv" class="h-48 w-48 m-12 border-gray-900 border-2">
        
</div>


@code {
    
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("initializeScrollListener");
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the JavaScript-Code:

```
window.initializeScrollListener = () => {
    console.log('Initializing scroll listener');
    window.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
        console.log('Wheel event detected');
        if (event.deltaY > 0) {
            console.log('Scrolling down');
            const targetElement = document.getElementById('testDiv');
            console.log('Target element found:', targetElement);
            if (targetElement) {
                targetElement.scrollIntoView({
                    behavior: 'smooth',
                    block: 'end' 
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
```

The JS-Code is in another file, but dont worry about wether the razor page even finds the JS-Code, because there arent any error and the logging works fine, its just that the auto. scroll to the div element doesnt happen and i cant figure out why?

I already tried finding solutions online but without success, so i would really appreciate it if someone could please help me with this problem, because i still have little experience with things like this!